# All things ADS (alas, TFS is no more...)

Tags: sql-server, team-foundation-server, azure-devops-server

After an in-place upgrade from TFS 2018 to ADS 2019, I'm in the process of migrating all of my `TFS` nomenclature to `ADS`. For example, the supporting service accounts have been changed from `TFS_Service` / `TFS_Build` / `TFS_Reports` to `ADS_Service` / `ADS_Build` / `ADS_Reports`.

I've completed all the service accounts and the Elastic Search extension as well (the index files were stored in `D:\TfsData`); I expect to have no difficulty with the DNS/ARR configurations.

However, I'm stuck on the Data Tier. My plans are to:

1. Install a new SQL Server instance
2. Point the Application Tier to the new instance
3. Restore from backup into the new instance

How can I edit the Application Tier to point to a new Data Tier? (It's currently at `SERVER3\TFS` and will change to `SERVER3\ADS`.) I'm finding documentation on migrating everything to new hardware, but nothing on simply pointing to a new Data Tier.